# How do I Debug Java Application Server in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am attempting to Debug a simple Java Server Application hosted on `localhost` on any given port. Within Eclipse I run it in debug mode to wait on an incoming connection. When I run my a browser to retrieve data from the server I get nothing.  If I run the Application outside of Eclipse, everything is fine and my pages are served.

Is there anything I need to do in Eclipse to enable ports or anything?

I saw this post:
[How does Eclipse debug code in an application server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343947/how-does-eclipse-debug-code-in-an-application-server)

but that is only informational.  Any help would be great.

Comment: what server are you using?

Answer (score 2):

To debug applications that run on another JVM or even on another machine, start them with these flags:

```
java -Xdebug -Xnoagent \ 
-Djava.compiler=NONE \ 
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

Enter the hostname and port to connect for debugging:

```
 Run → Debug Configuration... menu
```

Create a new debug configuration of the Remote Java Application type.
This configuration allows you to enter the hostname and port for the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Settings:
1.Click the Run Button
2.Select the Debug Configurations
3.Select the “Remote Java Application”
4.New Configuration
     a) Name : GatewayPortalProject
b) Project : GatewayPortal-portlet
c)  Connection Type: Socket Attach
d)  Connection Properties:
i)  localhost   ii) 8787

**For JBoss:**

1.Change the `/path/toJboss/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/standalone.conf` in your vm as follows:
   Uncomment the following line by removing the #:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"
```

**For Tomcat :**

In **catalina.bat** file :

Step 1:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Step 2:

```
JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Step 3: Run Tomcat from command prompt like below:

```
catalina.sh jpda start
```

Then you need to set breakpoints in the Java classes you desire to debug.

Hope this helps.